# Using sfepy to solve a simple 2D differential euqation

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, differential-equations, finite-element-analysis

I am trying to learn sfepy. To that effect I want to solve the differential equation

[image]

On a triangle domain (2D).

There';s 2 things I don't understand from reading the [docs](https://sfepy.org/doc-devel/tutorial.html#tutorial-interactive-source).

1. How do I specify a single triangle mesh? The code seems to assume you already have the mesh file but it does not provide a link to it so I don;t know hwo to cosntruct my data.
2. I am having a ahrd time learning how to map the equation onto sfepy's syntax. i.e. I don;t really know how to specify the problem using the library even after followignt he tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution to your problem 1.

The example script `linear_elastic_interactive.py`, does mention the path to the mesh used on line 35, like this `mesh = Mesh.from_file(data_dir + '/meshes/2d/rectangle_tri.mesh')` . And the tutorial also mentions that "**This file should be run from the top-level SfePy source directory so it can find the mesh file correctly**". So if you navigate the source code, you can find the mesh here: [link](https://github.com/sfepy/sfepy/blob/master/meshes/2d/rectangle_tri.mesh)